# textDocument/hover doesn't work until file is opened in vscode-languageclient/server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I tried to create a language client that communicates with an external language server via web sockets. The communication works well and all LSP functionalities are achieved if all the files are opened once. If we do not open the files, textDocument/hover is unable to resolve.

I tried to open all the files using openTextDocument() & showTextDocument() but still no luck!

Comment: If you cannot help others reproduce this (like using a sample repo on GitHub), I don't think any meaningful discussion can happen.

Comment: Why are you building an LSP language client which provides data about files without opening them? That doesn't seem like a typical IDE workflow. Are you looking to provide code intelligence on the web? If so - would either LSIF or Treesitter provide some better ways of solving that problem? https://lsif.dev https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/